# Sending email on behalf of users

Tags: amazon-ses, email, email-validation

I want to allow users to send emails to a list of addresses they have supplied.

If they supply their own domain I will send from their domain for them.

However, in the case they don't have their own domain I will send it from my domain address. I am wondering what a best practice 'from' address would be. Considering that I don't want users sender reputation to conflict.

Currently, my options are along the lines of:

1. `FROM: "{$userName}{$userId}mail@myapp.com"`
2. `FROM "mail@myapp.com"`

Option 2 would run the risk of sender reputation conflicts I imagine.

Are there any best practices or solutions for this problem?

Thanks